# java script string.match() doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, jsfiddle, console.log

I am trying to match a string with regex as below. Jsfiddle returns the array with matched string as expected. But if I run the below statement in browser console, it returns null. I tried in ie11,Chrome,Mozilla. Can anybody explain why this discrepancy? Am I missing something.

```
"201458".match(/^20['^\s']{4,}$|^$/)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not match. You are looking for `20` followed by four or more of apostrophe, caret or a whitespace character (followed by a string end); `1` is none of those.

- `['^]` is "apostrophe or caret".
- `[^']` is "not apostrophe".

Caret only has its special function when *at start* of the character class; apostrophe does not have any special function in a regexp.

If you find that this matches in jsfiddle, please link the said fiddle; I will be very surprised.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. But the think is, I am storing this expression XYZ.match(/^20[^\s]{4,}$|^$/) correctly in SQL Server Database. But when I retrieve it and pass the expression to browser javascript, the Apostrophes are getting added like this.  XYZ.match(/^20['^\s']{4,}$|^$/). I am using C# as the middle tier. Please let me know how to prevent this.

Comment: Can't, without knowing more: what specifically is in the database, and what code takes it out of the database and into the webpage, at minimum.